# WSL Debian 12: Systemd not working

Tags: debian, windows-subsystem-for-linux, systemd, wsl2

I tried to enable Systemd on a just installed Debian 12 distribution. It's just not working and I want to know why.
I want to have the current stable version of Debian and access to some repos. So I tried to import Debian 12 from a docker container export and with easyWSL.

MWE:

- Installing Debian 12 on WSL with docker or easyWSL
- `echo "[boot] systemd=true" > /etc/wsl.conf`
- restart wsl

Result:

```
PS C:\Users\user> wsl -d test
Catastrophic failure
Error code: Wsl/Service/CreateInstance/E_UNEXPECTED
```

I don't know what this error means or how to handle it. The only possibility to recover the distribution is to mount the `ext4.vhdx` in wsl and edit `/etc/wsl.conf` with another distribution.

It would be very helpful to get Bookworm running including systemd.

Thanks already :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Did you install these 2 packages:

```
apt install -y systemd systemd-sysv
```